# ImportError: No module named cv2 on macox

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, macos-sierra

I have used homebrew to install OpenCV, but I cannot use it, when I import OpenCV in Python, I meet this error:

```
ImportError: No module named cv2; op
```

[image]

- system:macos10.12.6
- opencv 3.3.0_2
- python 2.7.13

Comment: please copy the output and not a screen capture

Comment: my input is import cv2,output is Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named cv2

Comment: T.Y.Zhang you should edit your post to paste your console traceback instead of a picture of it. You could copy/paste to avoid us rewrite from picture.

Comment: To answer your question, you need to install opencv-python not opencv. See https://pypi.python.org/pypi/opencv-python

Comment: thank you very much,l have solved this issue!!!!!